# Spring Message Consumer is becoming offline after ActiveMQ Master/Slave

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jms, activemq-classic, spring-jms

I am facing problem with my Spring JMS Listener application which listens to the topic.

Whenever a master/slave transition happens on ActiveMQ, my consumer id is going from "Active Durable Subscribers" to "Offline Durable Subscribers" as reported by the ActiveMQ web console. If I restart my consumer application again it's becoming active under "Active Durable Subscribers." I am not sure what is wrong with my Spring Listener configuration.

```xml
<bean id="amqConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory"> 
    <property name="brokerURL" value="failover:(tcp://xxx01:61616,tcp://xxx02:61626)?randomize=false&amp;initialReconnectDelay=100&amp;maxReconnectDelay=100&amp;maxReconnectAttempts=30"/> 
    <property name="clientID" value="DevTest" />
</bean>

<bean id="connectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
    <constructor-arg ref="amqConnectionFactory" />
    <property name="reconnectOnException" value="true" />
</bean>

<bean id="messageReceiver" class="com.example.jms.TestMessageListener">
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory" />
    <property name="destinationName" value="TESTTOPIC" />
    <property name="messageListener" ref="messageReceiver" />
    <property name="subscriptionDurable" value="true" />
    <property name="pubSubDomain" value="true" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Have you tried increasing `maxReconnectAttempts` on your connection URL from 30 to something much higher?

Comment: Hi @JustinBertram, yes I did. I have changed it to 100 but still facing the same issue.

Comment: Remove the max reconnect attempts setting and see if it works, if so you need more attempts or longer delays.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with the ActiveMQ Artemis and helped delete connection parameters.

Works for me:
`(tcp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:61616,tcp:/xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:61617)`

Let`s try:

```
failover:(tcp://xxx01:61616,tcp://xxx02:61626)
```